# Let's get critical: Sep 2014 Site Self-Evaluation

Tags: discussion, site-evaluation

We all love [Robotics Stack Exchange](http://robotics.stackexchange.com), but there is a whole world of people out there who need answers to their questions and don't even know that this site exists. When they arrive from Google, what will their first impression be? Let's try to look at this site through the eyes of someone who's never seen it before, and see how we stack up against the rest of the 'Net.

The [Site Self-Evaluation review queue](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/review/site-eval) is open and populated with 10 questions that were asked and answered in the last quarter. 
Run a few Google searches to see how easy they are to find and compare the answers we have with the information available on other sites.

Rating the questions is only a part of the puzzle, though. Do you see a pattern of questions that should have been closed but are not? Questions or answers that could use an edit? Anything that's going really well? **Post an answer below to share your thoughts** and discuss these questions and the site's health with your fellow users!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Final Results

- [Cascading PID DC Motor Position & Velocity Controllers](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/questions/4318/cascading-pid-dc-motor-position-velocity-controllers)

**Net Score: 2** (Excellent: 2, Satisfactory: 0, Needs Improvement: 0)

---

- [Is a Genetic alogorithm suitable for mobile robot path planning?](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/questions/4393/is-a-genetic-alogorithm-suitable-for-mobile-robot-path-planning)

**Net Score: 1** (Excellent: 1, Satisfactory: 1, Needs Improvement: 0)

---

- [Are stereo camera calibration data standardized?](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/questions/4266/are-stereo-camera-calibration-data-standardized)

**Net Score: 1** (Excellent: 1, Satisfactory: 1, Needs Improvement: 0)

---

- [Calculate object distance with camera](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/questions/4296/calculate-object-distance-with-camera)

**Net Score: 1** (Excellent: 1, Satisfactory: 1, Needs Improvement: 0)

---

- [What is the difference between screw and wrench in rigid body motion?](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/questions/4277/what-is-the-difference-between-screw-and-wrench-in-rigid-body-motion)

**Net Score: 0** (Excellent: 0, Satisfactory: 2, Needs Improvement: 0)

---

- [What laser power for cutting and engraving wood and Acrylic robot baseplates?](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/questions/4399/what-laser-power-for-cutting-and-engraving-wood-and-acrylic-robot-baseplates)

**Net Score: 0** (Excellent: 0, Satisfactory: 2, Needs Improvement: 0)

---

- [Kalman filter Issue - GPS Odometry Fusion](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/questions/4287/kalman-filter-issue-gps-odometry-fusion)

**Net Score: 0** (Excellent: 0, Satisfactory: 1, Needs Improvement: 0)

---

- [Is there a rule of thumb for actuator torque overhead?](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/questions/4326/is-there-a-rule-of-thumb-for-actuator-torque-overhead)

**Net Score: 0** (Excellent: 0, Satisfactory: 1, Needs Improvement: 0)

---

- [Stepper does not turn](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/questions/4307/stepper-does-not-turn)

**Net Score: -1** (Excellent: 0, Satisfactory: 1, Needs Improvement: 1)

---

- [Mechanical or electrical engineering for robotic and automation?](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/questions/4362/mechanical-or-electrical-engineering-for-robotic-and-automation)

**Net Score: -2** (Excellent: 0, Satisfactory: 0, Needs Improvement: 2)

---